# Why android logcact keep showing Invalid notification data android Error Warning

Tags: android

**I have no idea what is going on with this message E/CatchNotificationsService: Invalid notification data android keep showing in the logcat. Does anybody have a clue about this error? What am i doing wrong? 
I really appreciate your help**